How can I estimate the velocity of a conveyor belt relative to a laser line profiler?
I have a laser line profiler scanning a conveyor belt:

At every time, step i: $t_i = i \Delta t$ the line profiler measures n points on the line:
$$
(Y_j,Z_j,I_j)
$$
Where $Y_j$ is the position along the line with $Y=0$ in the center of the line,
$Z_j$ is the height relative to the conveyor belt and $I_j$ is the intensity (greyscale value).
Let the line profiler define our world coordinate system: $\{X, Y, Z\}$.
Assume that the conveyor belt is moving with a constant velocity $-\vec{V}$ relative to this coordinate system.
Further, let us introduce a conveyor belt coordinate system: $\{x, y, z\}$ that is fixed to the moving conveyor belt. At $t=0$, the conveyor belt coordinate system equals the world coordinate system.
At a later time the origin of the conveyor belt coordinate system has moved: $-t\vec{V}$
wrt the world coordinate system.
Thus:
$$
[x, y, z] = [0,Y(t),Z(t)] + t[V_X,V_Y,V_Z]
$$
How can I determine the velocity vector $\vec{V}$?
I can not assume that the conveyor belt is perefectly level, nor that the Z axis is perfectly vertical.
My general idea is to place a calibration target with known positions in the conveyor belt coordinate system, e.g. the corners of a chess pattern, on the conveyor belt:

For each known point in the conveyor belt coordinate system: $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$, I would find the same point in the world coordinate system: $(0,Y_i,Z_i)$ at the time $t_i$.
From n such point correspondences:
$$
(x_i, y_i, z_i) <-> (t_i, Y_i, Z_i)  
$$
I should be able to estimate $[V_X,V_Y,V_Z]$ using nonlinear least squares parameter estimation.
In order to do this, I must formulate a penalty function:
$$
SE(V_X,V_Y,V_Z)
$$
such that wrong $V_X$, $V_Y$ and $V_Z$ is penalized, and minimize this function.
What penalty function should I use, and what requirements do I have on the target?
Must for instance the points be in more than one plane?
So far, what I have come up with is this:
I use the 4 corners of a 40 cm x 40 cm square:

I find these 4 corners in world coordinates: $(t_i,Y_i,Z_i)$ from the laser profiler line images.
Next, I assume a $[V_X,V_Y,V_Z]$ and calculate:
$$
(x_i, y_i, z_i) = (0,Y_i,Z_i) + t_i[V_X,V_Y,V_Z]
$$
From the corner positions in conveyor belt coordinates, I then calculate $d_1$, $d_2$ and $d_3$.
Next, I calculate SE from this equation:
$$
SE = (d1 - 40)^2 + (d2 - 40)^2 + (d3 - 40\sqrt{2})^2
$$
Finally I "vary" $[V_X,V_Y,V_Z]$ until I find the smallest SE value. This is the most likely velocity vector.
However one problem with my SE and target above is that I do not think this penalty function can distinguish between $V_X$ and $V_Z$.
For actually minimizing the function I will be using either scipy.optimize.curve_fit() or scipy.optimize.minimize().
My question is not about how to do this.

This seems more like an engineering question than a physics question. I think you want to maximize the autocorrelation function for your penalty function, but I don’t know any constraints

You would be better off attaching  a linear encoder to the conveyor belt and tracking speed with it.

I second Stevan's recommendation.  There's better ways to get this information.  Also, you mention that the transformation from ground-space to belt-space is a simple constant-speed relationship.  In this sense, you should be able to compute the direction of V trivially using the geometry of the belt.  If you need more than that, for misalignments of the belt, there's a good chance the constant-speed relationship assumption wont be sufficient as well.
